# Spotify: Permanent auth with authorization code workflow

Tags: spotify

i am building a prototype to prove deriving user playlist etc. from Spotify.
As this is user information, i've to use Spotify's authorization code workflow (refer https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow)

In this workflow, an application requests user to grant scoped privileges so relevant information can be pulled out.
In the series of calls that follow:

1. call to /authorize
   calls back a redirect_uri sent in request and sends in a code 
   e.g. 
   redirect_uri=../abc receives ../abc/callback?code=xyz

   as is exemplified in docs.
2. xyz is then sent over to /api/token to get access_token and refresh_token

Is there any way one can avoid to repeatedly invoke /authorize after once the grant has been given by user?

In-effect, can i not treat the code (from /authorize) like an oauth token and preserve it (say in database) to get a new access_token every time i need one? (as a direct comparison check facebook's oauth token that can be saved and reused to authenticate every next time)

How can i remember a user has already granted me access to his/her Spotify profile and data?

Please indicate if i am missing something obvious from documentation. please point me right if this has been specified elsewhere.

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case you can use the [Authorization Code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow). What you should persist is the `refresh_token` it returns, which can be used to obtain access tokens. You can also optionally persist the access token, that you can use during one hour, so you don't need to obtain a new access token every time.

There is a FAQ in the [Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) that talks about a similar scenario, where a user would want to manage her playlists without having to go through the login process every time:

> You basically need an access token and a refresh token issued for your user account. For obtaining a pair of access token / refresh token you need to follow the Authorization Code Flow (if you need a certain scope to be approved) or Client Credentials (if you just need to sign your request, like when fetching a certain playlist). Once you obtain them, you can use your access token and refresh it when it expires without having to show any login form.